# Word to describe the state of something being external or internal

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a word that refers to the state of being external or internal as a noun. Something like "ternality" or "ternalness" if those were words.

Example:

"The 'ternality' of the door was external."

Comment: The only word that I can think of that might fit would be "orientation":  "The orientation of the door was external."  This would mean that it's true position was external.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Yeah, I thought about that, but it's a little broad for what I'm looking for. I want something that explicitly refers to just that set. The word probably doesn't exist, but I figured I'd look around.

Comment: A related word that refers to the quality of being in one state or its mirror image is _chirality_ (synonym: _handedness_). Not exactly what you're looking for, but in a context in which external doors were mirror images of internal doors, this just might work.

Comment: I don't think there is a word for that, but if there were it should probably be a form of perimeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is *internal*, it's obviously *bounded* by the limits of whatever it's contained within (a house, your body, etc.). If it's *external* it must be outside those limits (it's *not* bounded). So...

> [**boundedness**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boundedness) *- the quality or state of being bounded* (Merriam-Webster)

---

For an obviously "boolean" attribute like this, it's also perfectly natural to simply use a word identifying *one* of the two possible states. Just as we can refer to the *truth* of a statement (an "attribute" whose value can be either *true* or *false*), so we could refer to the...

> **internality** *- the quality or fact of being internal (in various senses)* (OED)

...where the possible values of the boolean attribute are *internal* and *external*.

Comment: That's good, but that has more of the context of physical dimensions than what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Morgan: I think you need to [unbound your mind](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22unbound+your+mind%22) and accept that *most* language use is "metaphorical". Especially when you're trying to name something that's rarely referenced (or even *conceived of* as an "attribute") in normal life.

Comment: Good point. I suspect there isn't a word that perfectly encapsulates what I'm looking for, I'm just curious to see if there is.

Comment: @Morgan: Your only example *(internal/external door)* specifically relates to inside/outside a *building* or similar. If that's the *only* kind of distinction you want to reference, there might be a more appropriate term (but it'll probably still be an unusual / "neologistic" usage). Or you could just go with ***internality*** (OED: *The quality or fact of being internal*), which in context could considered be a "binary" attribute (akin to talking about the *truth* of a statement, when we mean the state of being ***either*** true ***or*** false).

Comment: Actually, I like using **internality** as a boolean state. That works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @Morgan: Okay, I've included that in the answer as well, in case these comments get deleted later.

Answer (score 1):

I read the great responses above. I thought about it and developed these two to explain both dimensions:

```
1. Inexternal, inexternality 
2. Exinternal, exinternality.
```

These words are using "in" interior and "ex" exterior to describe both internal and external state/condition of being/object/response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably looking for exogenous (external) vs endogenous (internal)...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that there is such a word. However, **placement**, n. comes close

OED:

> 1. The action or an act of placing (in various senses); **the fact or situation of being placed**; placing, **arrangement**, position.
>
> 1949   G. Shurr & R. D. Yocom Mod. Dance v. 125   *Lower left knee to floor without disturbing placement of extended toe.*

"The **placement** of the door was external."